# Update a Label Text in a ListView on Item Appearing

Tags: maui

I have a list view -

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Budget.Bills}" Margin="10,0,40,0" SeparatorVisibility="None" x:Name="LVOutgoings" RowHeight="130" SelectionMode="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" ItemAppearing="LVOutgoings_ItemAppearing">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5,10,5,15">
                    <BoxView HeightRequest="4" Margin="0" Color="{DynamicResource Success}" />
                    <Border BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource PictureFrame40}" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                                <Image Source="billsincome.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                            </Border>
                            <Label TextColor="{DynamicResource Success}" Text="" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="lblOutgoingheader"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding BillName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                            <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                <Label Text="{Binding BillType}" />
                            </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And in my code behind am using the Item Appearing -

```cs
private void LVOutgoings_ItemAppearing(object sender, ItemVisibilityEventArgs e)
{
    var Bill = (Bills)e.Item;
    var LV = (ListView)sender;

   //I want to update Text of each label in View cell in here
}
```

Basically as I cycle through each item in the Item Source I want to update the Label Text value in for that item depending on an object object.

I have tried playing about with it but cant figure out how to access any controls in the DataTemplate > ViewCell when the item is appearing.

Am I completely off base here and should be doing it a different way?

Comment: Why do you need to "cycle through each item" to update the text? What is that you are trying to accomplish with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we generally don't handle it in the way you said. We can use [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters) to convert the data you need to display, just as Jason mentioned. And we can also add a new property(e.g`public string Header { get; set; }`) for your bill model,and assign the correct value for the `Header` property based on the value of property `BillType`

Based on the code you shared,I created a demo and achieved this funciton with the two methods.

### The first way:

**Bill.cs**

```
public class Bill
{
    //public string Header { get; set; }
    public string BillName { get; set; }
    public string BillType { get; set;}
}
```

**MyBudgetViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyBudgetViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bill> Bills { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Bill>();

    public MyBudgetViewModel() {

        Bills.Add( new Bill {BillName ="Name1", BillType= "Test" });      
        Bills.Add( new Bill {BillName ="Name2", BillType= "Test2" });      
        Bills.Add( new Bill {BillName ="Name3", BillType= "Test3" });      
   
    }
}
```

**BillTypeToHeaderConverter.cs**

```
public class BillTypeToHeaderConverter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if (value == null) return null;

      string valueAsString = value as string;

      switch (valueAsString)
        {
            case "Test":
                return "Test Outgoing Added";

            case "Test2":
                return "Test2 Outgoing Added";
            default:
                 return "other header";

        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Usage exmaple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiCheckListviewApp.Views.MyListViewPage"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiCheckListviewApp.ViewModes"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MauiCheckListviewApp.Converters"
             Title="MyListViewPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:MyBudgetViewModel></viewmodels:MyBudgetViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:BillTypeToHeaderConverter x:Key="billTypeToHeaderConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}" Margin="10,0,40,0" SeparatorVisibility="None" x:Name="LVOutgoings" RowHeight="130" SelectionMode="None" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <VerticalStackLayout Padding="5,10,5,15">
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="4" Margin="0"  />
                            <Border BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Label  Text="{Binding BillType,Converter={StaticResource billTypeToHeaderConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="lblOutgoingheader"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding BillName}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                    <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding BillType}" />
                                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

### **The second way:**

You can add a new property(e.g`public string Header { get; set; }`) for your bill model,and assign the correct value for the `Header` property based on the value of property `BillType`.

```
public class Bill
{

    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string BillName { get; set; }
    public string BillType { get; set;}

    public Bill(string Name, string Type ) {
   
      this.BillName = Name;
      this.BillType = Type;


        if (BillType == "Test")
        {
            Header = "Test Outgoing Added";
        }
        else if (BillType == "Test2")
        {
            Header = "Test2 Outgoing Added";
        }
        else {
       
          this.Header ="other header";
        }
    }
}
```

And initialize the Bills in the viewmodel as follows:

```
public class MyBudgetViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Bill> Bills { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Bill>();

    public MyBudgetViewModel() {

        //Bills.Add( new Bill {BillName ="Name1", BillType= "Test" });      
        //Bills.Add( new Bill {BillName ="Name2", BillType= "Test2" });      
        //Bills.Add( new Bill {BillName ="Name3", BillType= "Test3" });      

        Bills.Add(new Bill ( "Name1", "Test" ));
        Bills.Add(new Bill ("Name2", "Test2"));
        Bills.Add(new Bill ("Name3", "Test3"));

    }
}
```

Then we can bind property `Header`  to the `lblOutgoingheader` Label as follows:

```
<Label  Text="{Binding Header}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Center" x:Name="lblOutgoingheader"/>
```

Comment: In practice I actually want to use more than Bill Type to format the header, I like the convertor approach more than Model, the reason I avoiding adding an extra field to my Model is I am using this in a couple of solutions and like to keep it the same (may not be any good reason for this but I prefer it this way). I assume though I can just pass the whole Object as {Binding .} instead of {Binding BillType} and update the convertor to work? Out of interest while I am learning what is the biggest Issue with assigning the values in the way I have, given I have made it work and seems to function?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit of a fool but will leave this up in case anyone else comes across a similar issue.

I was applying to the Appearing action to the Listview when I should have been doing it on the ViewCell. So the below will work perfectly

```
    private void ViewCell_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var vcBill = (ViewCell)sender;
    var Bill = (Bills)vcBill.BindingContext;        
    Label Header = (Label)vcBill.FindByName("lblOutgoingheader");

    if (Bill.BillType == "Test")
    {
        Header.Text = "Test Outgoing Added";
    }
    else if(Bill.BillType == "Test2")
    {
        Header.Text = "Test2 Outgoing Added";
    }
}
```

with the viewcell in the Xaml being

```
<ViewCell Appearing="ViewCell_Appearing">
```

Comment: This is absolutely the wrong way to do it.  You should bind the `Label` to a property of your model, and then update the model and let the binding update the UI for you.

Comment: you could also use an IValueConverter to set the text of the label based on the value of another property of the object